# Problem with booting Raspberry Pi 400 from USB drives

Tags: pi-4, boot, boot-issues, usb-hub, bootloader

**Summary:**

I have a USB3 flash drive that I can use to boot my Raspberry Pi 400 without a problem, but **only** when it is **directly attached** to one of my my RPI 400 USB3 ports.

However, when I attach the drive ***indirectly*** via a usb3 hub, the RPI can't seem to complete the boot process successfully.

**UPDATE: Could this boot failure be *timing* related?**

I am now starting to wonder if these symptoms are re
lated to the time it takes for a USB hub to be detected and the devices on it polled, vs. a limit on the time that the bootloader waits for a response by a bootable device.

**Hypothetically:**

1. Imagine Bootloader waits only 2 seconds for a response from a bootable USB device.
2. Boot loader send query to USB devices "are you bootable?" *t=0.0 sec.*
3. The 3 onboard USB ports initialize in .5 seconds. *t=0.5 sec*
4. USB Flash Drives receive requests .5 seconds after initialization. *t=1 sec*
5. USB Hub takes 1 second to initialize. *t=1.0 sec.*
6. USB Flash Drives responds .5 sec after requests received *t=1.5 sec* (direct connect USB boot succeeds!)
7. Devices on USB Hub take 1 additional second to initialize *t=2.0 sec*.
8. Bootable Device on USB Hub receives request *t=2.0 sec*
9. **Boot loader time out -- no longer listens for USB devices *t=2.0***
10. Bootable Device on USB Hub responds *t=2.5 sec*
11. Responses from hub mounted devices are received by bootloader *t=3.0 sec -- **1.0 second too late!**

If this hypothesis is correct, how can I:

1. **Increase the wait time** that the bootloader will wait for a USB device response.
2. direct the boot loader to look for a response from a *specific* USB device, connected via a *specific* USB hub path (eliminates delays from checking other USB items first).

**OBSERVED Failure Behavior:**
On power up the RPI will shortly bring up the rainbow window and then the boot process stalls out completely. It continues to show with the rainbow window never progressing to the X-desktop window. It also does not respond to keypresses, mouse actions, nor VNC or SSH network access requests.

**Research Results:**
In my research so far, I have determined that the rpi 400 can only address USB devices at a maximum depth or two levels of attached hubs.  However, this drive will only be at a depth of 1 hub, so that should not be the cause of this problem. Indeed, if I boot the RPI from a different device,  but with my USB drive remotely attached, the RPI  mounts both the **boot** and **rootfs** partitions from on the USB drive just fine. And I can read and write files in those partitions.

I have looked for, but I have not yet found, any documentation which shows any reason that the RPI 400 might be *forbidden* from booting from an indirectly connected USB drive. So, I am guessing that booting across a hub is allowed and *possible*, but that my problem is that I just don't know the correct way configure the boot in *raspi-config* for that to work.

I have also sought information which might tell the bootloader the ***specific*** USB device I want it to try to boot from, but I did not find any instructions for how to configure that behavior either.

*Can anyone advise me on how to achieve this goal?*

**BACKGROUND: Reason for connecting to USB drive *via a hub* (NOT *direct* through the rpi's ports)**

The reason I want to attach this boot disk via a separate hub, rather than directly to the RPI 400 ports, is that I am using the RPI as a **controller** for my *custom camera array appliance.*

Our custom appliance has more than 3 USB devices internal to it, so it needs an attached hub inside it anyway for the RPI to control all those devices.

To reduce the likelihood of tampering, it is desirable that device's storage (including its boot disk) be *internal to its enclosure* as well.

Comment: `without any further visible errors` ... what errors are visible?

Comment: The only visible error is that it never gets any further than showing a rainbow window.  It never paints the X desktop,  it never seems to respond to any keypresses, nor mouse actions.  It never begins responding to SSH network requests. It just acts hung.

Comment: You can change your eeprom to include USB_MSD_STARTUP_DELAY
see https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#raspberry-pi-4-bootloader-configuration